# TypeError: MySQLConnectionAbstract.__init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Tags: python, mysql-python, mysql-connector, mysql-connector-python, database-connection

I got the error below:

```
TypeError: MySQLConnectionAbstract.__init__() takes 1 positional argument but 
2 were given
```

Here is my `db.py`:

```
import mysql.connector

localhost = "localhost"
username = "Admin"
password = "test123"
db = "testing"
Connect = "host = '{}', user = '{}', password = '{}', db = '{}'".format(localhost, username, password, db)

cnn = mysql.connector.connect(Connect)  # line 16 error
# cnn = mysql.connector.connect(host ="localhost", user = "Admin", password = "test123", db = "testing")
```

If I write proper connect like below, then it worked.

```
cnn = mysql.connector.connect(host ="localhost", user = "Admin", password = "test123", db = "testing"
```

However, it won't work if I write the code like below:

```
cnn = mysql.connector.connect(Connect)
```

This is the completed error printed to the terminal:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\herok\Documents\MyApp 3\db.py", line 16, in <module>
    cnn = mysql.connector.connect(Connect)
  File "C:\Users\herok\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\__init__.py", line 273, in connect  
    return MySQLConnection(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\herok\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\connection.py", line 72, in __init__
    super(MySQLConnection, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: MySQLConnectionAbstract.__init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

Comment: The connect function doesn't define a connection string as one of its [arguments](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-connectargs.html), so it won't work.  Use the "proper connect".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using this approach

```
cnn = mysql.connector.connect(Connect)
```

You are passing a string to connect function but the function doesn't accept string, it should receive keyword arguments as you did in the second approach

```
cnn = mysql.connector.connect(host ="localhost", user = "Admin", password = "test123", db = "testing"
```

so if you need to keep the connection string parameter in a variable so you can pass it to the connect function

You can save the data as a dictionary add expand the dictionary when calling the function as the below

```
connection_string_params = {
"host":"localhost",
"user":"Admin",
"password":"test123",
"db":"testing"
}

cnn = mysql.connector.connect(**connection_string_params)
```

Answer (score 0):

The **connect()** method is not capable to parse a connection string, that's why the error is raised.

You can find the full list of arguments here:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-connectargs.html